# A question on the properties of a relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have some relations on the set [1,2,3,4].

1. $R_{1}=\{(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4)\}$
2. $R_{2}=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$
3. $R_{3}=\{(2,4),(4,2)\}$
4. $R_{4}=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$
5. $R_{5}=\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)\}$
6. $R_{6}=\{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,4)\}$

I need to determine if these relations are *reflexive/symmetric/anti-symmetric* and *transitive*.

Can someone please give me a detailed explanation on what we need to check to determine these properties. I'm very confused. I'm getting my answers wrong.

I will be very grateful, thanks a lot.

Comment: Check if the relations $R_1$ etc satisfy the properties defining [symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) etc. Symmetric means : $\forall x,y [xRy \leftrightarrow yRx]$.

Comment: Consider e.g. $R_1$; we have $(2,4) \in R_1$. What about $(4,2)$ ?

Comment: Yes, R1 is not symmetric. I'm getting more confused on anti symmetric and transitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is checking the definitions.

For example, let’s work $R_1$ out.

- Can $R_1$ be *reflexive*? Recall the definition:

  > A relation $R$ over a set $A$ is said to be reflexive iff *for each* $a \in A$ one has $(a,a) \in R$.

  The answer is **no**, because $(1,1) \notin R_1$.
- Can $R_1$ be *antireflexive*? Recall the definition:

  > A relation $R$ over a set $A$ is antireflexive iff *for each* $a \in A$ one has $(a,a) \notin R$.

  The answer is **no**, because $(2,2) \in R_1$.
- Can $R_1$ be *symmetric*? Recall the definition:

  > A relation $R$ over a set $A$ is symmetric iff *for each* $a \in A$ one has $(a,b) \in R \Rightarrow (b,a) \in R$.

  The answer is **no**, because $(2,4) \in R_1$ but $(4,2) \notin R_1$.
- Can $R_1$ be *antisymmetric*? Recall the definition:

  > A relation $R$ over a set $A$ is antisymmetric iff *for each* $a, b\in A$ one has $(a,b) \in R \land (b,a) \in R \Rightarrow a=b$.

  The answer is **no**, because $(2,3) \in R_1$ and also $(3,2) \in R_1$, but $2\neq 3$.
- Can $R_1$ be *asymmetric*? Recall the definition:

  > A relation $R$ over a set $A$ is asymmetric iff *for each* $a,b\in A$ one has $(a,b) \in R \Rightarrow (b,a) \notin R$.

  The answer is **no**, because $(2,3) \in R_1$ and $(3,2) \in R_1$.
- Can $R_1$ be *transitive*? Recall the definition:

  > A relation $R$ over a set $A$ is transitive iff *for each* $a,b,c \in A$ one has $(a,b) , (b,c) \in R \Rightarrow (a,c) \in R$.

  The answer is **yes**, because a *direct inspection* shows that each couple of possible consecutive connections $(a,b) , (b,c) \in R_1$ is closed by an arc $(a,c) \in R_1$. In fact:

  - the path $(2,2)$ & $(2,2)$ is closed by $(2,2)$;
  - the path $(2,2)$ & $(2,3)$ is closed by $(2,3)$;
  - the path $(2,2)$ & $(2,4)$ is closed by $(2,4)$;
  - the path $(2,2)$ & $(2,3)$ is closed by $(2,3)$;
  - the path $(2,3)$ & $(3,2)$ is closed by $(2,2)$;
  - the path $(2,3)$ & $(3,3)$ is closed by $(2,3)$;
  - the path $(2,3)$ & $(3,4)$ is closed by $(2,4)$;
  - the path $(3,2)$ & $(2,2)$ is closed by $(3,2)$;
  - the path $(3,2)$ & $(2,3)$ is closed by $(3,3)$;
  - the path $(3,2)$ & $(2,4)$ is closed by $(3,4)$;
  - the path $(3,3)$ & $(3,2)$ is closed by $(3,2)$;
  - the path $(3,3)$ & $(3,3)$ is closed by $(3,3)$;
  - the path $(3,3)$ & $(3,4)$ is closed by $(3,4)$.

Remaining relations can be studied in a similar fashion.

Comment: Did we conclude that this is transitive by using logic? Such as p implies q, but since p is false, q being false or true will mean our proposition is always true. Sorry if I am incorrect, I am confused in the relations chapter.

Comment: @SonnyJordan : No, it’s not logic. See the edited post. ;-)

Comment: Why didn't we check (2,4) or (3,4)?

Comment: Because there are no pairs in $R_1$ with $4$ in the first coordinate, i.e. there are no connections which are consecutive to $(2,4)$ and $(3,4)$.

Comment: Have you ever tried to draw the oriented graph of $R_1$?

Comment: No, I haven't. Sorry, should I? Is the oriented graph same as a directed graph?

Comment: Yes, it’s the same. Sometimes I find it useful drawing a picture of what I’m doing. Maybe you’ll find it useful too. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A relation $R$ on set $A$ is said to be **reflexive** if $\forall a \in A ~ (a,a) \in R$.

A relation $R$ on set $A$ is said to be **symmetric** if $ (a,b) \in R \mathrm{~then~} (b,a) \in R$. $\phi$ is also symmetric.

A relation $R$ on set $A$ is said to be **anti-symmetric** if $ (a,b) \in R \mathrm{~and~} (b,a) \in R  \mathrm{~then~} a = b$. No symmetric pair must be present.

A relation $R$ on set $A$ is said to be **Transitive** if $(a,b) \in R \mathrm{~and~} (b,c) \in R \mathrm{~then~} (a,c) \in R$.

---

$R_1$ does not have $(4,2)$ hence it is not symmetric although it is reflexive, transitive. However $R_1$ is not antisymmetric (as we have symmetric pairs).